# Angular js (1.5) date filter: making it modular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

I have this sprinkled in various different templates in my app.

```
<span>
  {{value.date | date : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm" : 'PDT'}} PDT
</span
```

I'll always use the same date format throughout the app.

I'm trying to figure out how to modularize the above so that I'm not repeating the same thing everywhere. I *think* the right way to do this is to make a component and then just use that wherever I need. E.g.

```
<formatted-date value="value"></formatted-date>
```

but I'm not sure if that is the correct way or if I should use a service/controller instead...?

[The docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) mention using

```
$filter('date')(date, format, timezone)
```

but I'm a bit lost as to where that would go in the general scheme of things (service/controller?).

(Apologies in advance if this is a stupid simple question or if I'm using the wrong terminology...I'm new to Angular and still trying to figure out the right way to do things.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Have you thought about [creating a custom filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter#creating-custom-filters)?** You could then replace all instances with:

`{{value.date | myDateFormat}}`

Heres an example:

```
app.filter('myDateFormat', ['$filter', function ($filter) {

    return function (input) {

        if (input) { 

            // set your dateFormat and timezone here
            var dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm";
            var timezone = "PDT";

            // format your date
            var formattedDate = $filter('date')(new Date(input), dateFormat,  timezone);

            return formattedDate;

        };

        return "";

    };

}]);
```

This will enable you to use the same date format and easily change it in the future.

**Otherwise**, If you are looking to always keep the `span` tags and `PDT` text too, then yes, create a component that you can re-use where you need it. You can achieve this by **using a [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)**.

You can provide a template and pass in the `$filter` service to your directive and do the same logic there.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case you can use angular i18n.
Just choose a locale file from [angular locale cdn](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/angular-i18n) then change as you want and import it in your project. 
You can change almost everything, including filters.
To changed default date filter just change the value of `"mediumDate"` to what you want. e.g: `"dd/MM/yyyy"` 
Angular i18n docs [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n)

EN-US Locale example:

```
'use strict';
angular.module("ngLocale", [], ["$provide", function($provide) {
var PLURAL_CATEGORY = {ZERO: "zero", ONE: "one", TWO: "two", FEW: "few", MANY: "many", OTHER: "other"};
function getDecimals(n) {
  n = n + '';
  var i = n.indexOf('.');
  return (i == -1) ? 0 : n.length - i - 1;
}

function getVF(n, opt_precision) {
  var v = opt_precision;

  if (undefined === v) {
    v = Math.min(getDecimals(n), 3);
  }

  var base = Math.pow(10, v);
  var f = ((n * base) | 0) % base;
  return {v: v, f: f};
}

$provide.value("$locale", {
  "DATETIME_FORMATS": {
    "AMPMS": [
      "AM",
      "PM"
    ],
    "DAY": [
      "Sunday",
      "Monday",
      "Tuesday",
      "Wednesday",
      "Thursday",
      "Friday",
      "Saturday"
    ],
    "ERANAMES": [
      "Before Christ",
      "Anno Domini"
    ],
    "ERAS": [
      "BC",
      "AD"
    ],
    "FIRSTDAYOFWEEK": 6,
    "MONTH": [
      "January",
      "February",
      "March",
      "April",
      "May",
      "June",
      "July",
      "August",
      "September",
      "October",
      "November",
      "December"
    ],
    "SHORTDAY": [
      "Sun",
      "Mon",
      "Tue",
      "Wed",
      "Thu",
      "Fri",
      "Sat"
    ],
    "SHORTMONTH": [
      "Jan",
      "Feb",
      "Mar",
      "Apr",
      "May",
      "Jun",
      "Jul",
      "Aug",
      "Sep",
      "Oct",
      "Nov",
      "Dec"
    ],
    "STANDALONEMONTH": [
      "January",
      "February",
      "March",
      "April",
      "May",
      "June",
      "July",
      "August",
      "September",
      "October",
      "November",
      "December"
    ],
    "WEEKENDRANGE": [
      5,
      6
    ],
    "fullDate": "EEEE, MMMM d, y",
    "longDate": "MMMM d, y",
    "medium": "MMM d, y h:mm:ss a",
    "mediumDate": "MMM d, y",
    "mediumTime": "h:mm:ss a",
    "short": "M/d/yy h:mm a",
    "shortDate": "M/d/yy",
    "shortTime": "h:mm a"
  },
  "NUMBER_FORMATS": {
    "CURRENCY_SYM": "$",
    "DECIMAL_SEP": ".",
    "GROUP_SEP": ",",
    "PATTERNS": [
      {
        "gSize": 3,
        "lgSize": 3,
        "maxFrac": 3,
        "minFrac": 0,
        "minInt": 1,
        "negPre": "-",
        "negSuf": "",
        "posPre": "",
        "posSuf": ""
      },
      {
        "gSize": 3,
        "lgSize": 3,
        "maxFrac": 2,
        "minFrac": 2,
        "minInt": 1,
        "negPre": "-\u00a4",
        "negSuf": "",
        "posPre": "\u00a4",
        "posSuf": ""
      }
    ]
  },
  "id": "en-us",
  "localeID": "en_US",
  "pluralCat": function(n, opt_precision) {  var i = n | 0;  var vf = getVF(n, opt_precision);  if (i == 1 && vf.v == 0) {    return PLURAL_CATEGORY.ONE;  }  return PLURAL_CATEGORY.OTHER;}
});
}]);
```

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood my question.... @papakia's answer is more what I was looking for.